# JPanel won't show on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

Here is the code

```
import Sprites.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
public class Main {
public int Health = 100;
public int ArmourPt = 0;
public int Gold = 250;
public static JLabel Goldlbl = new JLabel("Gold:");
public static JLabel Healthlbl = new JLabel("Health:");
public static JLabel ArmourPtLbl = new JLabel("Armour Points");
public static JFrame MainWindow = new JFrame();
    public static int CalcDamage(int Damage, int Armour){
    int ReturnDamage = Damage - Armour + Damage / Damage + Armour / Damage * Damage -         Armour + Damage + 25 ;
    if(ReturnDamage < 0){
        ReturnDamage = 0;
    }
    return ReturnDamage;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MainWindow.setSize(1500, 700);
    MainWindow.setTitle("Ampventure");;

    JPanel MPanel = (JPanel)MainWindow.getContentPane();
    MPanel.setLayout(null);

    JPanel StatsPanel = new JPanel();
    StatsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
    StatsPanel.setSize(350, 450);
    StatsPanel.setLocation(0, 0);
    StatsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension (350, 450));
    MPanel.add(StatsPanel);

    JPanel InvPanel = new JPanel();
    InvPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
    InvPanel.setSize(350, 212);
    InvPanel.setLocation(0, 450);
    StatsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension (350, 250));
    MPanel.add(InvPanel);

    JPanel DisplayPanel = new JPanel();
    DisplayPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
    DisplayPanel.setSize(1135, 450);
    DisplayPanel.setLocation(350, 0);
    MPanel.add(DisplayPanel);

    JPanel ControlPanel = new JPanel();
    ControlPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
    ControlPanel.setSize(1135, 212);
    ControlPanel.setLocation(350, 1135);
    MPanel.add(ControlPanel);

    MainWindow.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

What is is supposed to do: Split up the screen into four parts using JPanels

What it does: Shows three of the panels, Stats, Inv, and Display, but not Control.

NOTE! I have had this said to me before, so let me state this now. I have NO plans and DO NOT WANT to use a layout manager. The dimensions of this have to be very specific and I don't want to use tricks to just use a layout manager. Please keep this in mind when answering. It's okay if you mention it, but please don't outright say 'Use a layout manager' Thank you.

Comment: `"but please don't outright say 'Use a layout manager'"` -- 1) Isn't it kind of presumptuous to specify what volunteers giving free advice should or shouldn't say? 2) Aren't you implying by this that you feel that you're wiser in the ways of layouts then the Swing experts on this site? And if so, why ask for help here?

Comment: This kind of problem is what layout managers are designed for. You will have a difficult time getting things to lay out in their proper size without a manager

Comment: Is there a layout manager where I can specify where everything goes with numerical co-ordinates? If so I would look into that, but as far as I know, there is none.

Comment: @user2839482: if there isn't you can create your own layout manager, but most layouts including complex ones can be created by nesting components that use simple layout managers. Before you tell folks not to give good advice, learn to listen and study that advice. Your specifications are foolish in the extreme.

Comment: @user2839482 GridBagLayout: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: I am just saying to not tell me I have to use a layout manager. I like freedom to put things where I want them to exactly.

Comment: Until you come across a system which has different font metrics, DPI and or screen resolution, then your pixel perfect layout falls over - just saying - it's your choice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ControlPanel.setLocation(350, 1135);
```

should be

```
ControlPanel.setLocation(350, 450);
```

and then you should be fine.

And maybe you should name your variables with a starting lowerCase, I always got confused as if they were class names and used like statics.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked! I am still very new in java. Also sorry about the names. Force of habit.

Comment: It's just a suggestion to make your code more readable. And the layout error was probably just some copy/paste mistake.

By the way, to debug your layout I used different border colors and commented them all out - just to see that the last one was not showed. Then I set the location to `0, 0` to see what happened. And then I just moved it to the right position.

Just to give you an idea of how to try to solve your problem on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Three things...

1. You should make sure you start you UI's within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details
2. Make sure you actually add your content (`MPanel`) to the frame (`MainWindow`) before you make it visible
3. Avoid using `null` layouts

You might also want to take a look at [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: Per the stipulations and requirements of the original poster, you're not allowed to post recommendation #3. 1+ for posting it anyway.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I said "avoid" ;)

Comment: I'd also recommend that he should "avoid" using all those static fields, but this idiot just pisses me off by his silly-a** requirements.

Comment: They are not requirements. If i didn't put that there would be tons of people posting to use a layout manager. It's happened before.

Comment: @user2839482: because it is the correct advice to give. For example please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20037116/522444) to see some of the flexibility of use of layouts, and why 99% of the time we **strongly urge** you not to use null layouts.

Comment: @MadProgrammer "make sure [to] add you[r] content [...] to the frame" - since MPanel is the contentPane of MainWindow, it should actually be added by default, or am I wrong?

Comment: @SebastianHöffner Yes, you are right, took me a while to make heads an tails of the code, so paint 3 stands out more importantly now ;)