# Java GUI Calculator

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, calculator, jtextarea

My `JTextArea` does not display and no errors or problems shows up. It's a Java GUI Calculator.

Main class code:

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;


    public class calulator_main{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            calulator_ui frame = new calulator_ui();
            frame.frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
```

Calculator code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;        
import javax.swing.*;        
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class calulator_ui extends calulator_main {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("cal");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel screen = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(1,20);
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton button7 = new JButton("7");

    JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
    JButton button0 = new JButton("0");

    JButton add = new JButton("+");
    JButton subtract = new JButton("-");
    JButton mutliple = new JButton("*");
    JButton divide = new JButton("/");
    JButton equals = new JButton("=");

    JButton clear = new JButton("C");

    JLabel label = new JLabel();



    double numberone,numbertwo,result;


    int addc=0, subc=0,mutlic=0,divc=0;






    public calulator_ui() {
        ui();
        placeComponets();
        createListeners();



    }




    public void placeComponets(){

        screen.add(text, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(button0);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(button3);
        panel.add(button4);
        panel.add(button5);
        panel.add(button6);
        panel.add(button7);
        panel.add(button8);
        panel.add(button9);
        panel.add(add);
        panel.add(mutliple);
        panel.add(subtract);
        panel.add(divide);
        panel.add(clear);
        panel.add(equals);
        panel.add(label);
    }


    public void ui(){

        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setSize(250,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);

    }




    public void createListeners(){

        this.button0.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.button1.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.button2.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.button3.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.button4.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.button5.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.button6.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.button7.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.button8.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.button9.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.add.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.subtract.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.mutliple.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.divide.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });
        this.equals.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        onCutClicked(ae);
                    }
                });



    }

    void onCutClicked(ActionEvent ae){

        Object source = ae.getSource();

        if(source==button0)
        {
            text.append("0");

        }   

        if(source==button1)
        {
            text.append("1");

        }   

        if(source==button2)
        {
            text.append("2");

        }   

        if(source==button3)
        {
            text.append("3");

        }   

        if(source==button4)
        {
            text.append("4");

        }   

        if(source==button5)
        {
            text.append("5");

        }   

        if(source==button6)
        {
            text.append("6");

        }   

        if(source==button7)
        {
            text.append("7");

        }   

        if(source==button8)
        {
            text.append("8");

        }   

        if(source==button9)
        {
            text.append("9");


        }

        if (source==add)
        {
            numberone=number_reader();
            text.setText("");
            addc=1;
            subc=0;
            mutlic=0;
            divc=0;
        }

        if (source==subtract)
        {
            numberone=number_reader();
            text.setText("");
            addc=0;
            subc=1;
            mutlic=0;
            divc=0;
        }

        if (source==mutliple)
        {
            numberone=number_reader();
            text.setText("");
            addc=0;
            subc=0;
            mutlic=1;
            divc=0;
        }

        if (source==divide)
        {
            numberone=number_reader();
            text.setText("");
            addc=0;
            subc=0;
            mutlic=0;
            divc=1;
        }



        if (source==equals)
        {
            numbertwo=number_reader();
            if (addc>0)
            {
                result=numberone+numbertwo;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));
            }

            if (subc>0)
            {
                result=numberone-numbertwo;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));
            }

            if (divc>0)
            {
                result=numberone/numbertwo;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));
            }

            if (mutlic>0)
            {
                result=numberone*numbertwo;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));
            }

        }
    }









    public double number_reader()

    {

        double returnnumber;
        String numberstring;
        numberstring=text.getText();
        returnnumber=Double.valueOf(numberstring);

        return returnnumber;


    }


}
```

Any suggestions on improvements to the code?

Comment: Step back and read a basic Java Swing tutorial before proceeding.

Comment: Java coding conventions have classes starting with an upper case letter written in CamelCase (CalcultorUI); methods and fields start with a lower case letter in camelCase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding your JTextArea, text, to your screen JPanel,

```
screen.add(text, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

but you're adding screen to nothing, and so it makes complete sense that the JTextArea won't show. You should add the JTextArea to a container that somehow is either directly or indirectly added to your JFrame, else it's not going to show. There's no magic here -- the GUI will only show what you add to it.

Note that since your JTextArea is written to be a single row, why not just use a JTextField instead? But regardless, the container hierarchy of this component must reach the top level window.

As an aside, read up on and learn about arrays and ArrayLists as you can use this and for loops to shorten your program considerably, making it much easier to read, understand and debug.

Please have a look at the code in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20037116/522444) to see what I mean. It will produce this GUI:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !! it has been a great help !!

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at your code, you have tried to pass Panel with arguments.
Use one layout, add the components that will be managed by that particular layout then another manager followed by its components.
 Declaring as you have done will make JVM to use only BorderLayout.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JPanel screen = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another calc code :)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Calculator {
private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 410;
private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;
private static final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 80; // Button width
private static final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 70; // Button height
private static final int MARGIN_X = 20;
private static final int MARGIN_Y = 60;

private JFrame window; // Main window
private JTextField inText; // Input text
private JButton btnC, btnBack, btnMod, btnDiv, btn7, btn8, btn9,
        btnMul, btn4, btn5, btn6, btnSub, btn1, btn2, btn3, btnAdd, btnPoint, btn0, btnEqual, btnRoot, btnPower, btnLog, btnSwitchThemes, btnSwitchToScientificMode;
private char opt = ' '; // Save the operator
private boolean go = true; // For calculate with Opt != (=)
private boolean addWrite = true; // Racordé des Nombres dans l'Affichage
private double val = 0; // Save value typed for calculation
private boolean isToggleColorSelected = false;
private boolean isScientificMode = false;

/*
    Mx Calculator: 
    X = Row
    Y = Column

    +-------------------+
    |   +-----------+   |   y[0]
    |   |           |   |
    |   +-----------+   |
    |                   |
    |   C  <-   %   /   |   y[1]
    |   7   8   9   *   |   y[2]
    |   4   5   6   -   |   y[3]
    |   1   2   3   +   |   y[4]
    |   .   0     =     |   y[5]
    +-------------------+
     x[0] x[1] x[2] x[3]

*/

/*    
    +-------------------+
    |   +-----------+   |   y[0]
    |   |           |   |
    |   +-----------+   |
    |                   |
    |   0   1   1   3   |   y[1]
    |   4   5   6   7   |   y[2]
    |   8   9   10  11  |   y[3]
    |   12  13  14  15  |   y[4]
    |   16  17    18    |   y[5]
    +-------------------+
     x[0] x[1] x[2] x[3]

*/

private Calculator() {
    window = new JFrame("Calculator");
    window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT); // Set the width and the Height of the window
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Move Window To Center

    // Button fonts
    Font btnFont = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 28);
    Font smallTxtBtnFont = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 24);

    btnSwitchThemes = new JButton();
    btnSwitchThemes.setBounds(230, 30, 140, 18);
    btnSwitchThemes.setText("Toggle colors");
    btnSwitchThemes.setBackground(Color.GREEN.darker());
    btnSwitchThemes.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnSwitchThemes.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnSwitchThemes.addActionListener(event -> onSwitchTheme());
    window.add(btnSwitchThemes);

    btnSwitchToScientificMode = new JButton();
    btnSwitchToScientificMode.setBounds(30, 30, 140, 18);
    btnSwitchToScientificMode.setText("Scientific Mode");
    btnSwitchToScientificMode.setBackground(Color.BLUE.darker());
    btnSwitchToScientificMode.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnSwitchToScientificMode.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnSwitchToScientificMode.addActionListener(event -> onShowScientificMode());
    window.add(btnSwitchToScientificMode);

    int j = -1;
    int k = -1;
    int[] x = {MARGIN_X, MARGIN_X + 90, 200, 290, 380};
    int[] y = {MARGIN_Y, MARGIN_Y + 100, MARGIN_Y + 180, MARGIN_Y + 260, MARGIN_Y + 340, MARGIN_Y + 420};

    inText = new JTextField("0");
    inText.setBounds(x[0], y[0], 350, 70);
    inText.setEditable(false);
    inText.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    inText.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 33));
    window.add(inText);

    btnC = new JButton("C");
    btnC.setBounds(x[0], y[1], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnC.setFont(btnFont);
    btnC.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnC.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        inText.setText("0");
        opt = ' ';
        val = 0;
    });
    window.add(btnC);

    btnBack = new JButton("<-");
    btnBack.setBounds(x[1], y[1], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnBack.setFont(btnFont);
    btnBack.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnBack.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        String str = inText.getText();
        StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < (str.length() - 1); i++) {
            str2.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
        if (str2.toString().equals("")) {
            inText.setText("0");
        } else {
            inText.setText(str2.toString());
        }
    });
    window.add(btnBack);

    btnMod = new JButton("%");
    btnMod.setBounds(x[2], y[1], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnMod.setFont(btnFont);
    btnMod.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnMod.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (Pattern.matches("([-]?\\d+[.]\\d*)|(\\d+)", inText.getText()))
            if (go) {
                val = calc(val, inText.getText(), opt);
                if (Pattern.matches("[-]?[\\d]+[.][0]*", String.valueOf(val))) {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf((int) val));
                } else {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                }
                opt = '%';
                go = false;
                addWrite = false;
            }
    });
    window.add(btnMod);

    btnDiv = new JButton("/");
    btnDiv.setBounds(x[3], y[1], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnDiv.setFont(btnFont);
    btnDiv.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnDiv.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (Pattern.matches("([-]?\\d+[.]\\d*)|(\\d+)", inText.getText()))
            if (go) {
                val = calc(val, inText.getText(), opt);
                if (Pattern.matches("[-]?[\\d]+[.][0]*", String.valueOf(val))) {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf((int) val));
                } else {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                }
                opt = '/';
                go = false;
                addWrite = false;
            } else {
                opt = '/';
            }
    });
    window.add(btnDiv);

    btn7 = new JButton("7");
    btn7.setBounds(x[0], y[2], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btn7.setFont(btnFont);
    btn7.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btn7.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (addWrite) {
            if (Pattern.matches("[0]*", inText.getText())) {
                inText.setText("7");
            } else {
                inText.setText(inText.getText() + "7");
            }
        } else {
            inText.setText("7");
            addWrite = true;
        }
        go = true;
    });
    window.add(btn7);

    btn8 = new JButton("8");
    btn8.setBounds(x[1], y[2], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btn8.setFont(btnFont);
    btn8.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btn8.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (addWrite) {
            if (Pattern.matches("[0]*", inText.getText())) {
                inText.setText("8");
            } else {
                inText.setText(inText.getText() + "8");
            }
        } else {
            inText.setText("8");
            addWrite = true;
        }
        go = true;
    });
    window.add(btn8);

    btn9 = new JButton("9");
    btn9.setBounds(x[2], y[2], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btn9.setFont(btnFont);
    btn9.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btn9.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (addWrite) {
            if (Pattern.matches("[0]*", inText.getText())) {
                inText.setText("9");
            } else {
                inText.setText(inText.getText() + "9");
            }
        } else {
            inText.setText("9");
            addWrite = true;
        }
        go = true;
    });
    window.add(btn9);

    btnMul = new JButton("*");
    btnMul.setBounds(x[3], y[2], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnMul.setFont(btnFont);
    btnMul.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnMul.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (Pattern.matches("([-]?\\d+[.]\\d*)|(\\d+)", inText.getText()))
            if (go) {
                val = calc(val, inText.getText(), opt);
                if (Pattern.matches("[-]?[\\d]+[.][0]*", String.valueOf(val))) {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf((int) val));
                } else {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                }
                opt = '*';
                go = false;
                addWrite = false;
            } else {
                opt = '*';
            }
    });
    window.add(btnMul);

    btn4 = new JButton("4");
    btn4.setBounds(x[0], y[3], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btn4.setFont(btnFont);
    btn4.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btn4.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (addWrite) {
            if (Pattern.matches("[0]*", inText.getText())) {
                inText.setText("4");
            } else {
                inText.setText(inText.getText() + "4");
            }
        } else {
            inText.setText("4");
            addWrite = true;
        }
        go = true;
    });
    window.add(btn4);

    btn5 = new JButton("5");
    btn5.setBounds(x[1], y[3], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btn5.setFont(btnFont);
    btn5.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btn5.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (addWrite) {
            if (Pattern.matches("[0]*", inText.getText())) {
                inText.setText("5");
            } else {
                inText.setText(inText.getText() + "5");
            }
        } else {
            inText.setText("5");
            addWrite = true;
        }
        go = true;
    });
    window.add(btn5);

    btn6 = new JButton("6");
    btn6.setBounds(x[2], y[3], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btn6.setFont(btnFont);
    btn6.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btn6.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (addWrite) {
            if (Pattern.matches("[0]*", inText.getText())) {
                inText.setText("6");
            } else {
                inText.setText(inText.getText() + "6");
            }
        } else {
            inText.setText("6");
            addWrite = true;
        }
        go = true;
    });
    window.add(btn6);

    btnSub = new JButton("-");
    btnSub.setBounds(x[3], y[3], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnSub.setFont(btnFont);
    btnSub.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnSub.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (Pattern.matches("([-]?\\d+[.]\\d*)|(\\d+)", inText.getText()))
            if (go) {
                val = calc(val, inText.getText(), opt);
                if (Pattern.matches("[-]?[\\d]+[.][0]*", String.valueOf(val))) {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf((int) val));
                } else {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                }

                opt = '-';
                go = false;
                addWrite = false;
            } else {
                opt = '-';
            }
    });
    window.add(btnSub);

    btn1 = new JButton("1");
    btn1.setBounds(x[0], y[4], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btn1.setFont(btnFont);
    btn1.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btn1.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (addWrite) {
            if (Pattern.matches("[0]*", inText.getText())) {
                inText.setText("1");
            } else {
                inText.setText(inText.getText() + "1");
            }
        } else {
            inText.setText("1");
            addWrite = true;
        }
        go = true;
    });
    window.add(btn1);

    btn2 = new JButton("2");
    btn2.setBounds(x[1], y[4], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btn2.setFont(btnFont);
    btn2.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btn2.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (addWrite) {
            if (Pattern.matches("[0]*", inText.getText())) {
                inText.setText("2");
            } else {
                inText.setText(inText.getText() + "2");
            }
        } else {
            inText.setText("2");
            addWrite = true;
        }
        go = true;
    });
    window.add(btn2);

    btn3 = new JButton("3");
    btn3.setBounds(x[2], y[4], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btn3.setFont(btnFont);
    btn3.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btn3.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (addWrite) {
            if (Pattern.matches("[0]*", inText.getText())) {
                inText.setText("3");
            } else {
                inText.setText(inText.getText() + "3");
            }
        } else {
            inText.setText("3");
            addWrite = true;
        }
        go = true;
    });
    window.add(btn3);

    btnAdd = new JButton("+");
    btnAdd.setBounds(x[3], y[4], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnAdd.setFont(btnFont);
    btnAdd.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnAdd.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (Pattern.matches("([-]?\\d+[.]\\d*)|(\\d+)", inText.getText()))
            if (go) {
                val = calc(val, inText.getText(), opt);
                if (Pattern.matches("[-]?[\\d]+[.][0]*", String.valueOf(val))) {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf((int) val));
                } else {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                }
                opt = '+';
                go = false;
                addWrite = false;
            } else {
                opt = '+';
            }
    });
    window.add(btnAdd);

    btnPoint = new JButton(".");
    btnPoint.setBounds(x[0], y[5], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnPoint.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 32));
    btnPoint.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnPoint.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (addWrite) {
            inText.setText(inText.getText() + ".");
        } else {
            inText.setText("0.");
            addWrite = true;
        }
        go = true;
    });
    window.add(btnPoint);

    btn0 = new JButton("0");
    btn0.setBounds(x[1], y[5], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btn0.setFont(btnFont);
    btn0.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btn0.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (addWrite) {
            if (Pattern.matches("[0]*", inText.getText())) {
                inText.setText("0");
            } else {
                inText.setText(inText.getText() + "0");
            }
        } else {
            inText.setText("0");
            addWrite = true;
        }
        go = true;
    });
    window.add(btn0);

    btnEqual = new JButton("=");
    btnEqual.setBounds(x[2], y[5], 2 * BUTTON_WIDTH + 10, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnEqual.setFont(btnFont);
    btnEqual.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnEqual.addActionListener(event -> {
        if (Pattern.matches("([-]?\\d+[.]\\d*)|(\\d+)", inText.getText()))
            if (go) {
                val = calc(val, inText.getText(), opt);
                if (Pattern.matches("[-]?[\\d]+[.][0]*", String.valueOf(val))) {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf((int) val));
                } else {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                }
                opt = '=';
                addWrite = false;
            }
    });
    window.add(btnEqual);

    btnRoot = new JButton("√");
    btnRoot.setBounds(x[4], y[1], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnRoot.setFont(btnFont);
    btnRoot.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnRoot.addActionListener(event -> {
        if (Pattern.matches("([-]?\\d+[.]\\d*)|(\\d+)", inText.getText()))
            if (go) {
                val = Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(inText.getText()));
                if (Pattern.matches("[-]?[\\d]+[.][0]*", String.valueOf(val))) {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf((int) val));
                } else {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                }
                opt = '√';
                addWrite = false;
            }
    });
    btnRoot.setVisible(false);
    window.add(btnRoot);

    btnPower = new JButton("pow");
    btnPower.setBounds(x[4], y[2], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnPower.setFont(smallTxtBtnFont);
    btnPower.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnPower.addActionListener(event -> {
        repaintFont();
        if (Pattern.matches("([-]?\\d+[.]\\d*)|(\\d+)", inText.getText()))
            if (go) {
                val = calc(val, inText.getText(), opt);
                if (Pattern.matches("[-]?[\\d]+[.][0]*", String.valueOf(val))) {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf((int) val));
                } else {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                }
                opt = '^';
                go = false;
                addWrite = false;
            } else {
                opt = '^';
            }
    });
    btnPower.setVisible(false);
    window.add(btnPower);

    btnLog = new JButton("log");
    btnLog.setBounds(x[4], y[3], BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btnLog.setFont(smallTxtBtnFont);
    btnLog.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnLog.addActionListener(event -> {
        if (Pattern.matches("([-]?\\d+[.]\\d*)|(\\d+)", inText.getText()))
            if (go) {
                val = Math.log(Double.parseDouble(inText.getText()));
                if (Pattern.matches("[-]?[\\d]+[.][0]*", String.valueOf(val))) {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf((int) val));
                } else {
                    inText.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                }
                opt = 'l';
                addWrite = false;
            }
    });
    btnLog.setVisible(false);
    window.add(btnLog);

    window.setLayout(null);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // If Click into The Red Button => End The Processes
    window.setVisible(true);
}

private double calc(double x, String input, char opt) {
    inText.setFont(inText.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
    double y = Double.parseDouble(input);
    if (opt == '+') {
        return x + y;
    } else if (opt == '-') {
        return x - y;
    } else if (opt == '*') {
        return x * y;
    } else if (opt == '/') {
        return x / y;
    } else if (opt == '%') {
        return x % y;
    } else if (opt == '^') {
        return Math.pow(x, y);
    }
    inText.setFont(inText.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
    return y;
}

private void repaintFont() {
    inText.setFont(inText.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
}

private void onSwitchTheme() {
    if (isToggleColorSelected) {
        btnSwitchThemes.setText("Toggle colors");
        btnSwitchThemes.setBackground(Color.GREEN.darker());
        btnSwitchThemes.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnC.setBackground(null);
        btnBack.setBackground(null);
        btnMod.setBackground(null);
        btnDiv.setBackground(null);
        btnMul.setBackground(null);
        btnSub.setBackground(null);
        btnAdd.setBackground(null);
        btnRoot.setBackground(null);
        btnLog.setBackground(null);
        btnPower.setBackground(null);
        btnEqual.setBackground(null);
        btn0.setBackground(null);
        btn1.setBackground(null);
        btn2.setBackground(null);
        btn3.setBackground(null);
        btn4.setBackground(null);
        btn5.setBackground(null);
        btn6.setBackground(null);
        btn7.setBackground(null);
        btn8.setBackground(null);
        btn9.setBackground(null);
        btnPoint.setBackground(null);

        btnC.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnBack.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnMod.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnDiv.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnMul.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnSub.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnAdd.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnEqual.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnLog.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnPower.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnRoot.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        isToggleColorSelected = false;
    } else {
        btnSwitchThemes.setText("Untoggle colors");
        btnSwitchThemes.setBackground(null);
        btnSwitchThemes.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnC.setBackground(Color.RED);
        btnBack.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        btnMod.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        btnDiv.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        btnMul.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        btnSub.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        btnAdd.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        btnRoot.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        btnLog.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        btnPower.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        btnEqual.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        btn0.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btn1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btn2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btn3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btn4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btn5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btn6.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btn7.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btn8.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btn9.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnPoint.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        btnC.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnBack.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        btnMod.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnDiv.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnMul.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnSub.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnAdd.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnEqual.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnLog.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnPower.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnRoot.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        isToggleColorSelected = true;
    }
}

private void onShowScientificMode() {
    if (isScientificMode) {
        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        btnRoot.setVisible(false);
        btnPower.setVisible(false);
        btnLog.setVisible(false);
        isScientificMode = false;
    } else {
        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH + 80, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        btnRoot.setVisible(true);
        btnPower.setVisible(true);
        btnLog.setVisible(true);
        isScientificMode = true;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Calculator();
}
```

}