# Can I make a for statement with the names of JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, calendar, jbutton

I'm programming a calendar for only one year in NetBeans and for the GUI I plan to have the typical calendar a spinner for the year. This combination will determine in which day of the week does de first and last day of the month goes.

The problem I have with the code I made is with using the Calendar day button's names as variables. Maybe there is a way to prepare a statement for NetBeans to read as the buttons name?

For this calendar, I made a JPanel with 49 buttons (to have 7 rows of weeks that is the maximum a calendar has). I tried to name every button "N(number)" (the number being from 1 to 49). This is so I can make a for function that makes so that the position of the day after the last day of a month will be the position for the first day of the following month.

[Image of the JPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8rCT.png)

The code for this would start from January 2022 (without counting leap-years). The year of the Calendar has to be specified in the "YearC" variable (int his case its 2022). Another value also has to be specified is the number of empty position in the calendar before the first day of the year in the "FirstD" variable (in the case of January 2022 it's 5). Finally, I used a spinner for the months because the user has to se the months consecutively for the code to work.

The code is the following:

```
    public void WeekPos(){
        String MonIntCal = MonthCal.getValue().toString();
        int DayN = 0;
        int jub = 0;
        int DayC = 0;
        int FirstD = 6;
        String YearC = "2022";
        YearCal.setText(YearC);
        String Nam = "B"+DayC;
        int LastJan = 0;
        int LastFeb = 0;
        int LastMar = 0;
        int LastApr = 0;
        int LastMay = 0;
        int LastJun = 0;
        int LastJul = 0;
        int LastAug = 0;
        int LastSep = 0;
        int LastOct = 0;
        int LastNov = 0;
        
        switch(MonIntCal){
            case "January": DayN = 31; jub = 1;
            case "February": DayN = 28; jub = 2;
            case "March": DayN = 31; jub = 3;
            case "April": DayN = 30; jub = 4;
            case "May": DayN = 31; jub = 5;
            case "June": DayN = 30; jub = 6;
            case "July": DayN = 31; jub = 7;
            case "August": DayN = 31; jub = 8;
            case "September": DayN = 30; jub = 9;
            case "October": DayN = 31; jub = 10;
            case "November": DayN = 30; jub = 11;
            case "December": DayN = 31; jub = 12;
        }
        switch(jub){
            case 1: for (int i = 1; i<FirstD; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>DayN+FirstD; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN; i=i+1){
                         DayC = 5+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                    }
                    LastJan = DayN+5;
            case 2: for (int i = 1; i<LastJan; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>LastJan; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN+1; i=i){
                        DayC = LastJan+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                        if(i==DayN){
                            LastFeb = DayC;
                        }    
                    };
            case 3: for (int i = 1; i<LastFeb; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>LastFeb; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN+1; i=i){
                        DayC = LastFeb+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                        if(i==DayN){
                            LastMar = DayC;
                        }    
                    };
            case 4: for (int i = 1; i<LastMar; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>LastMar; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN+1; i=i){
                        DayC = LastMar+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                        if(i==DayN){
                            LastApr = DayC;
                        }    
                    };
            case 5: for (int i = 1; i<LastApr; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>LastApr; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN+1; i=i){
                        DayC = LastApr+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                        if(i==DayN){
                            LastMay = DayC;
                        }    
                    };
            case 6: for (int i = 1; i<LastMay; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>LastMay; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN+1; i=i){
                        DayC = LastMay+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                        if(i==DayN){
                            LastJun = DayC;
                        }    
                    };
            case 7: for (int i = 1; i<LastJun; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>LastJun; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN+1; i=i){
                        DayC = LastJun+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                        if(i==DayN){
                            LastJul = DayC;
                        }    
                    };
            case 8: for (int i = 1; i<LastJul; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>LastJul; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN+1; i=i){
                        DayC = LastJul+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                        if(i==DayN){
                            LastAug = DayC;
                        }    
                    };
            case 9: for (int i = 1; i<LastAug; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>LastAug; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN+1; i=i){
                        DayC = LastAug+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                        if(i==DayN){
                            LastSep = DayC;
                        }    
                    };
            case 10: for (int i = 1; i<LastSep; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>LastSep; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN+1; i=i){
                        DayC = LastSep+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                        if(i==DayN){
                            LastOct = DayC;
                        }    
                    };
            case 11: for (int i = 1; i<LastOct; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>LastOct; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN+1; i=i){
                        DayC = LastOct+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                        if(i==DayN){
                            LastNov = DayC;
                        }    
                    };
            case 12: for (int i = 1; i<LastNov; i=i+1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);  
                    }
                    for (int i = 49; i>LastNov; i=i-1){
                        DayC = i;
                        Nam.setText(null);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<DayN+1; i=i){
                        DayC = LastNov+i;
                        if(DayC>49){
                         DayC=DayC-49;   
                        }
                        Nam.setText(i.toString());
                    };    
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

So, as I understand things, your main question is, "can I create a bunch of JButtons based on an array or collection of Strings that represent the button text", and the answer, as you'd expect, is yes, and quite easily. For instance, say you wanted a collection of buttons that represented the months of the year, you could start with an array of Month names, like so:

```
private static final String[] MONTHS = { 
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
        "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
        "November", "December" };
```

And then iterate through this array, creating buttons that display the names from the array:

```
for (String month : MONTHS) {
    JButton button = new JButton(month);
    someJPanel.add(button);
}
```

The problem that you're going to run into is, how to figure out which button was pressed, an important bit of information. This can be solved in many ways, the simplest is to pass the String of interest to the button's ActionListener. These listeners can be created "in-line" using a lambda expression like so:

```
for (String month : MONTHS) {
    JButton button = new JButton(month);
    button.addActionListener(e -> monthButtonListener(month));
    someJPanel.add(button);
}
```

This lambda calls a method, `monthButtonListener(...)` that gets the button's text via a String parameter:

```
private void monthButtonListener(String month) {
    // the month name is passed into the parameter and can be used however desired
    // here as an example, by printing out the String:
    System.out.println("Month selected: " + month);
}
```

Another common way to get the button's text is via its action listener's "action command" property which can be obtained from the ActionEvent parameter that is passed into the listener's actionPerformed method, like so:

Again, create the buttons, but this time, pass the ActionEvent parameter into the monthButtonListener:

```
for (String month : MONTHS) {
    JButton button = new JButton(month);
    button.addActionListener(e -> monthButtonListener(e));
    add(button);
}
```

Then change the monthButtonListener method to accept an ActionEvent parameter and extract its action command property:

```
private void monthButtonListener(ActionEvent e) {
    // can also get the button's text as its "actionCommand":
    System.out.println("Button text: " + e.getActionCommand());
}
```

A small demonstration program could like something like so:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ButtonFoo01 extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] MONTHS = { 
            "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
            "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
            "November", "December" };
    
    public ButtonFoo01() {
        int gap = 3;
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4, gap, gap));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
        
        for (String month : MONTHS) {
            JButton button = new JButton(month);
            button.addActionListener(e -> monthButtonListener(e));
            add(button);
        }
    }
    
    private void monthButtonListener(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Button text: " + e.getActionCommand());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            ButtonFoo01 mainPanel = new ButtonFoo01();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

You also can see another example of mine that uses a 2-dimensional array of Strings to help create a GUI calculator,

[image]

in my answer here:

[Java JComponent paint --Almost working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20037116/522444)

---

## But...

Having answered the direct question, one also has to consider the overall problem, that of creating an accurate calendar representation using a Swing GUI, a problem that involves calendar logic that is well-suited to use of the relatively new DateTime Java library. This library makes it fairly easy to create a combo box for months since one can use the library's Month enum as the data nucleus of the JComboBox:

```
private JComboBox<Month> monthCombo = new JComboBox<>(Month.values());
```

The year could  be represented by a JSpinner, one that uses a SpinnerNumberModel that has been set to the desired starting and ending year:

```
private JSpinner yearSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(2022, 1900, 3000, 1));
```

I would also change the spinner's editor so that it doesn't display a thousands comma delimiter:

```
JSpinner.NumberEditor editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(yearSpinner, "#");
yearSpinner.setEditor(editor);
```

Also, we can add the same listener to the JComboBox as to the JSpinner, one that takes both values and finds the correct month for the selected year:

```
yearSpinner.addChangeListener(ce -> dateChanged());
monthCombo.addItemListener(ie -> dateChanged());
```

with the `dateChanged()` method:

```
private void dateChanged() {
    int year = (int) yearSpinner.getValue();
    Month month = (Month) monthCombo.getSelectedItem();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
    
    // this notifies the JPanel that displays the dates of the selected month and year
    daysOfMonthPanel.setDate(date);
}
```

An example program could look something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CalendarGui extends JPanel {
    public static final String LOCAL_DATE = "local date";
    private JSpinner yearSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(2022, 1900, 3000, 1));
    private JComboBox<Month> monthCombo = new JComboBox<>(Month.values());
    private DaysOfTheMonthPanel daysOfMonthPanel = new DaysOfTheMonthPanel();

    public CalendarGui() {
        JSpinner.NumberEditor editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(yearSpinner, "#");
        yearSpinner.setEditor(editor);
        yearSpinner.addChangeListener(ce -> dateChanged());
        monthCombo.addItemListener(ie -> dateChanged());
        monthCombo.setRenderer(new MonthComboEditor());
        yearSpinner.setMaximumSize(yearSpinner.getPreferredSize());
        monthCombo.setMaximumSize(monthCombo.getPreferredSize());

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        topPanel.add(yearSpinner);
        topPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        topPanel.add(monthCombo);
        
        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        middlePanel.add(new DaysOfTheWeekPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        middlePanel.add(daysOfMonthPanel);        

        int gap = 3;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(gap, gap));
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(middlePanel);
        
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        yearSpinner.setValue(now.getYear());
        monthCombo.setSelectedItem(now.getMonth());
    }
    
    private void dateChanged() {
        int year = (int) yearSpinner.getValue();
        Month month = (Month) monthCombo.getSelectedItem();
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
        
        // this notifies the JPanel that displays the dates of the selected month and year
        daysOfMonthPanel.setDate(date);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            CalendarGui mainPanel = new CalendarGui();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static class MonthComboEditor extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                boolean cellHasFocus) {
            String newValue = (value == null) ? "" : ((Month) value).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US);
            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, newValue, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        }
    }
    
    private static class DaysOfTheWeekPanel extends JPanel {
        private static final float FONT_SZ = 24;
        public DaysOfTheWeekPanel() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 7));
            int numberDaysOfWk = DayOfWeek.values().length;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberDaysOfWk; i++) {
                int sundayIsZero = (i + numberDaysOfWk - 1) % numberDaysOfWk;
                JLabel wkDayLabel = new JLabel(DayOfWeek.values()[sundayIsZero].getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, getLocale()));
                wkDayLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                Font font = wkDayLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, FONT_SZ);
                wkDayLabel.setFont(font);
                add(wkDayLabel);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private class DaysOfTheMonthPanel extends JPanel {
        public DaysOfTheMonthPanel() {
            int gap = 2;
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 7, gap, gap));
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, gap));
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        
        public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
            removeAll();
            int year = date.getYear();
            Month month = date.getMonth();
            LocalDate firstOfMonth = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
            DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = firstOfMonth.getDayOfWeek();
            int daysInMonth = YearMonth.of(year, month).lengthOfMonth();
            
            // fill empty slots with empty JLabels
            for (int i = 0; i < dayOfWeek.getValue() % 7; i++) {
                add(new JPanel());
            }
            
            for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(i), SwingConstants.CENTER);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, i);
                panel.putClientProperty(LOCAL_DATE, localDate);
                panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                int topBtm = 25;
                int side = 45;
                panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(topBtm, side, topBtm, side));
                panel.add(label);
                panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        String format = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
                        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
                        System.out.println("Date pressed: " + localDate.format(formatter));
                    }
                });
                add(panel);
            }
            
            // fill in w/ jpanels until end of month
            LocalDate lastDayOfMonth = LocalDate.of(year, month, daysInMonth);
            int lastDayOfWeek = lastDayOfMonth.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
            int daysLeft = (7 + 6 - lastDayOfWeek) % 7; 
            for (int i = 0; i < daysLeft; i++) {
                add(new JPanel());
            }
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```